# How can I change an external swf's dimention in Actionscript project?

Tags: actionscript, flash, dimension

I used Loader to load an external swf file, and try to display it in a fixed area, like a fixed dimention sprite object.  And I don't know the exact size of the swf file, I just want it to fit the fixed area.  Is that possible?

code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("some path"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
function completeHandler(e:Event):void
{
    var loaderinfo:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
    loaderinfo.content.width = 300;
    loaderinfo.content.height = 300;
    loaderinfo.content.x = 0;
    loaderinfo.content.y = 0;//note that this works for displaying picture, but not for swf
    thePanel.stage.addChild(loader);
}
```

I want the swf to fit the panel's area. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `loaderInfo.content.height` try `loaderInfo.loader.height`.

If this still doesn't work for you, try this:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChlid(loaderInfo.loader);
container.width = 300;
container.height = 300;
thePanel.addChild(container)
```

...in your Event.COMPLETE listener.

Comment: still not work, so I doubt that if it's an impossible mission.
Or we cannot use conventional weapon for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
addChild(loader); //you can add it, as it is kind of proxy display object container
function completeHandler(e:Event):void { 
  loader.width = 300; 
  loader.height = 300; 
  loader.x = 0; 
  loader.y = 0;
}
```